# How to run shell script in EC2 at a specific time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to run shell srcipt in EC2 Instance when i want to do.

so I thought 3 ways how can i do this problem.

1. To run shell script in EC2 from Lambda at a specific time using EventBridge.
   https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/
2. To run SSM Run Command at a specific time using EventBridge
   https://medium.com/the-cloud-architect/creating-your-own-chaos-monkey-with-aws-systems-manager-automation-6ad2b06acf20
3. To run shell script with cron by installing cron tab package on EC2
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html

Which method is the best in terms of performance or maintenance?

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is very generic. Being "best in maintenance" is subjective and comes down to you personal abilities. For some, cron is best and easiest to use, for others it will not be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, depending on the complexity of what you want to run, crontab is easy and lightweight. I am not entirely positive, but I'm pretty sure crontab is installed on EC2 by default.

To view the current scheduled cron entries, you can run the following: `crontab -l`

To edit the cron jobs, run the following: `crontab -e`

*Note: It will use the default `EDITOR` which is typically either vi or vim.*

You can find out more about the syntax for crontab [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm).